# Efficient reading/transforming partitioned data in delta lake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I have my data in a delta lake in ADLS and am reading it through Databricks. The data is partitioned by year and date and z ordered by storeIdNum, where there are about 10 store Id #s, each with a few million rows per date. When I read it, sometimes I am reading one date partition (~20 million rows) and sometimes I am reading in a whole month or year of data to do a batch operation. I have a 2nd much smaller table with around 75,000 rows per date that is also z ordered by storeIdNum and most of my operations involve joining the larger table of data to the smaller table on the storeIdNum (and some various other fields - like a time window, the smaller table is a roll up by hour and the other table has data points every second). When I read the tables in, I join them and do a bunch of operations (group by, window by and partition by with lag/lead/avg/dense_rank functions, etc.).

**My question is: should I have the date in all of the joins, group by and partition by statements?** Whenever I am reading one date of data, I always have the year and the date in the statement that reads the data as I know I only want to read from a certain partition (or a year of partitions), but is it important to also reference the partition col. in windows and group bus for efficiencies, or is this redundant? After the analysis/transformations, I am not going to overwrite/modify the data I am reading in, but instead write to a new table (likely partitioned on the same columns), in case that is a factor.

For example:

```
dfBig = spark.sql("SELECT YEAR, DATE, STORE_ID_NUM, UNIX_TS, BARCODE, CUSTNUM, .... FROM STORE_DATA_SECONDS WHERE YEAR = 2020 and DATE='2020-11-12'")
dfSmall = spark.sql("SELECT YEAR, DATE, STORE_ID_NUM, TS_HR, CUSTNUM, .... FROM STORE_DATA_HRS WHERE YEAR = 2020 and DATE='2020-11-12'")
```

Now, if I join them, do I want to include YEAR and DATE in the join, or should I just join on STORE_ID_NUM (and then any of the timestamp fields/customer Id number fields I need to join on)? I definitely need STORE_ID_NUM, but I can forego YEAR AND DATE if it is just adding another column and makes it more inefficient because it is more things to join on. I don't know how exactly it works, so I wanted to check as by foregoing the join, maybe I am making it more inefficient as I am not utilizing the partitions when doing the operations?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key with delta is to choose the partitioned columns very well, this could take some trial and error, if you want to optimize the performance of the response, a technique I learned was to choose a filter column with low cardinality (you know if the problem is of time series, it will be the date, on the other hand if it is about a report for all clients in that case it may be convenient to choose your city), remember that if you work with delta each partition represents a level of the file structure where its cardinality will be the number of directories.

In your case I find it good to partition by YEAR, but I would add the MONTH given the number of records that would help somewhat with the dynamic pruning of spark

Another thing you can try is to use BRADCAST JOIN if the table is very small compared to the other.

[Broadcast Hash Join en Spark (ES)](https://riptutorial.com/es/apache-spark/example/25482/broadcast-hash-join-en-spark)

[Join Strategy Hints for SQL Queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#join-strategy-hints-for-sql-queries)

The latter link explains how dynamic pruning helps in MERGE operations.

[How to improve performance of Delta Lake MERGE INTO queries using partition pruning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/delta/delta-merge-into)